# Initializing a std::map iterator class member

Tags: c++, iterator, initialization, decltype

I'm trying to do this:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, time_t> my_map;
const mymap& some_function();

class bla
{
private:
  my_map::iterator current
  bla(const mymap& m) : current(m.begin())
  {   }
}
```

And it's not working. The somewhat more convoluted real error message is:

> error: no matching function for call to 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator, long int> >::_Rb_tree_iterator(std::map, long int>::const_iterator)'

I tried moving the initialization/assignment to the constructor body:

```
{ current = m.begin(); }
```

Which didn't work either. So I thought, the type of `current` is wrong, so I just let the compiler deduce that:

```
...
   decltype(my_map::begin()) current;
...
```

Which doesn't work either.

All I need is an iterator member that is set at `bla` construction time, so I don't have to explicitly set it in some stupid extra function and can iterate over the map externally through:

```
bool bla::do_stuff(...output...)
{ 
    if(current = m.end())
        return false;
    balblabla(current);
    ++current;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to assign `const_iterator` to `iterator`. There are two solutions:

1. Take map by non-const reference (`bla(my_map& m) : current(m.begin()) {}`).
2. Change the member type to `const_iterator`.

Answer (score 4):

In a const context, you can only obtain a `const_iterator`:

```
my_map::const_iterator current;
bla(const my_map & m) : current(m.begin()) { }
```

If you want a non-const iterator, you have to construct your `bla` object from a non-constant reference.